# VIM8 & flake8 doesn't work when there are chinese words in it

Tags: python, python-3.x, vim-plugin, chinese-locale

Everything went well when all words in my file are in English, but when I use codes like "print("你好")", or even use a comment like "# 你好", then flake8 stopped working, and only display "an exception was thrown. See ALEDetail" in the first line.[I use w0rp/ale as plugin in vim80]

If I enter :ALEDetail in the vim, the information looks like below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\utils.py", line 82, in _stdin_get_value_py3
    return io.StringIO(stdin_value.decode(coding))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 92: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "D:\ProgrammingTool\python\python35\Scripts\flake8.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\main\cli.py", line 16, in main
    app.run(argv)
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\main\application.py", line 396, in run
    self._run(argv)
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\main\application.py", line 384, in _run
    self.run_checks()
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\main\application.py", line 309, in run_checks
    self.file_checker_manager.start(files)
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\checker.py", line 342, in start
    self.make_checkers(paths)
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\checker.py", line 246, in make_checkers
    checker for checker in checkers if checker.should_process
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\checker.py", line 246, in <listcomp>
    checker for checker in checkers if checker.should_process
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\checker.py", line 243, in <genexpr>
    if should_create_file_checker(filename, argument)
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\checker.py", line 378, in __init__
    self.processor = self._make_processor()
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\checker.py", line 392, in _make_processor
    return processor.FileProcessor(self.filename, self.options)
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\processor.py", line 61, in __init__
    self.lines = self.read_lines()
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\processor.py", line 297, in read_lines
    lines = self.read_lines_from_stdin()
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\processor.py", line 333, in read_lines_from_stdin
    return utils.stdin_get_value().splitlines(True)
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\utils.py", line 95, in stdin_get_value
    stdin_value = _stdin_get_value_py3()
  File "d:\programmingtool\python\python35\lib\site-packages\flake8\utils.py", line 84, in _stdin_get_value_py3
    return io.StringIO(stdin_value.decode('utf-8'))
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb6 in position 92: invalid start byte
```